# Websockets for background processing

Tags: http, node.js, backgroundworker, websocket

Is it a good idea to use Websockets (comet, server push, ...) to overcome a problem with long running HTTP requests? Imagine you have an app, build on full-stack web app framework, like Django, or Rails. You want to do some background processing in the name of performance. That's easy to do from programmer perspective, but the problem arises in the UI.

Users demand immediate response. So my idea was to use Socket.IO + node.js + AMQP messaging, to push notifications back to browsers, once the background task completed. I like the idea, but it still feels like lots of engineering, just because we don't want to long running requests in our main app. Competing idea could be to use another, more robust, web server, that can handle many long running HTTP requests.

Which one you think is better?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it a good idea to use Websockets to
>   overcome a problem with long running HTTP requests?

Yes it is. You can save singificant amount of data when compared to other techniques, such as continuous or long polling. Try to look at [this article](http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2009/12/7/real-time-online-activity-monitor-example-with-node-js-and-websocket), namely the Step 3 part.

> I like the idea, but it still feels like lots of engineering, just
>   because we don't want to long running requests in our main app.
>   Competing idea could be to use another, more robust, web server, that
>   can handle many long running HTTP requests.

Socket.io abstracts transport layer and fallback solutions (in case of websockets absence) for you. If you want to use socket.io/node.js/AMPQ stack only for messaging and notifications then it shouldn't be a complex or time consuming development process, however it may depend on various stuff around.

By delegating messaging/notifications to node.js you may disburden your main app to great extent thanks to its non-blocking architecture although you will introduce dependency on another technology.

On the other hand choosing more performant web server may solve your performance concerns for some time, but you may eventually end up with scaling your system (either up or out).

Answer (score 1):

WebSockets in themselves provide little here over e.g. XHR or jsonp long polling. From the user's perspective, messaging over either transport would feel the same. From the server's perspective, an open WebSocket connection or an open long poll isn't *violently* different.

What you're really doing, and should be doing regardless of the underlying technology, is build your application to be asynchronous - event driven.

Comment: on NODEJS yes, but consider php + apache. each long poll would aquire one process on the server side.